# How to rewrite csv file on client with java web application

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am new in java web application, (Java EE, JSF).

I tried to change the contents of a csv file on the client computer with a java web application, so that the client does not have to download a new file, because the file is already in the set to be used for applications in the client. so I just wanted to rewrite the csv file.

Could it be done in java web application? If yes, please give me an example. I am very grateful if there is a better solution.

Comment: possible through policy configuration and Applet, but might be too complex to implement. Creating something client software like dropbox would be a better approach. Or follow Kevin answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not. You can't change the contents of a file on a client computer from a web browser. The best you could do is have them upload a version of a file and then send them another version to download. Giving write access to the filesystem would be a massive security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Place the CSV on a network share somewhere.  The client can edit it, the back-end server can edit it.  Requires more infrastructure, of course, but may work depending on the type of application.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I think this is what you want, but if the 'client computer' was also acting as the server (i.e. was the host running Jetty/Tomcat/whatever), then you could modify files on it using the java IO api.

Again, very likely not what you want, just saying it would work.